# what is the Optimization of the c++ matrix calculation with opencv::Mat

Tags: c++, numpy, opencv, llvm, mat

I have below codes which 2X is slower than the llvm optimized numpy/python version which is:

numpy.sum(numpy.square(desc - desc_2))

How can I improve below opencv matrix code in c++:

```
   cv::Mat broad;
   cv::Mat features
   broad = features - cmp;
   cv::pow(broad,2,broad);
   cv::reduce(broad, broad, 1, cv::REDUCE_SUM);
```

which is both numpy and Mat is (512 X float) matrix

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are continous, i.e. `desc.isContinuous()` is true, you can get pointers to your matrices and calculate the sum of squared differences by hand, which takes roughly 2 milliseconds on my laptop for two 512-by-1024 double precision matrices.

However, you can get about the same performance in Python by using

`np.linalg.norm(desc - desc_2)**2`

instead of

`np.sum(np.square(desc - desc_2))`.

`np.linalg.norm` is faster because, unlike the other method, it sums the differences directly after squaring without storing them into RAM and reading them back first. This is important here because the computation is mostly limited by memory bandwidth.

You can improve performance further by using 32-bit single precision floats (`CF_32F`) or even smaller data types instead of 64-bit doubles (`CF_64F`) if precision is not important for your application, because it decreases the number of bytes to be transmitted. If you go that route, you might even consider using SSE or AVX instructions in case you are not be bottlenecked by memory bandwidth anymore.

## C++ example

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for (int test = 0; test < 10; test++){
        // initialize matrices with random data
        cv::Mat desc1(512, 1024, CV_64F);
        cv::Mat desc2(512, 1024, CV_64F);
        randu(desc1, cv::Scalar(0.0), cv::Scalar(1.0));
        randu(desc2, cv::Scalar(0.0), cv::Scalar(1.0));

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        // get pointers to first elements of matrices
        double *ptr1 = desc1.ptr<double>(0);
        double *ptr2 = desc2.ptr<double>(0);

        double sum = 0.0;
        cv::Size size = desc1.size();
        // sum the squared differences between all elements
        for (int i = 0; i < size.width * size.height; i++){
            double difference = ptr1[i] - ptr2[i];
            sum += difference * difference;
        }

        auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        double nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(elapsed).count();
        double milliseconds = nanoseconds * 1e-6;

        std::cout << "result C++: " << sum << ", " << milliseconds << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## Timing results for C++ example

```
result C++: 87452.5, 2.83437 milliseconds
result C++: 87382.4, 1.92824 milliseconds
result C++: 87334.1, 1.93404 milliseconds
result C++: 87409, 1.92608 milliseconds
result C++: 87524, 1.9333 milliseconds
result C++: 87352.1, 2.1178 milliseconds
result C++: 87390.5, 1.95265 milliseconds
result C++: 87325.5, 2.14512 milliseconds
result C++: 87361.8, 1.95677 milliseconds
result C++: 87687.6, 2.10184 milliseconds
```

## Python example

```py
import time
import numpy as np

for _ in range(10):
    desc1 = np.random.rand(512, 1024)
    desc2 = np.random.rand(512, 1024)

    t0 = time.perf_counter()

    s = np.sum(np.square(desc1 - desc2))

    t1 = time.perf_counter()

    print("result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)):", s, 1000*(t1 - t0), "milliseconds")

print("")

for _ in range(10):
    desc1 = np.random.rand(512, 1024)
    desc2 = np.random.rand(512, 1024)

    t0 = time.perf_counter()

    s = np.linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)**2

    t1 = time.perf_counter()

    print("result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)):", s, 1000*(t1 - t0), "milliseconds")
```

## Timing results for Python example

```
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87074.95194414 25.832481998804724 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87248.23486227753 4.291343997465447 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87298.36234439172 4.271910001989454 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87335.12881267883 4.619887000444578 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87329.50342643914 5.444231999717886 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87622.93760898946 4.942010997183388 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87376.8813873815 5.2427179980441 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87419.14640286344 4.6821379983157385 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87193.05495816837 4.524519001279259 milliseconds
result  sum(square(desc1 - desc2)): 87327.52989629997 5.168449999473523 milliseconds

result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87418.11425419849 2.766734000033466 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87433.25400706155 3.2142550007847603 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87295.75712318903 2.63671799984877 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87300.2682143185 3.1689810020907316 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87430.74565029072 2.64247700033593 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87384.7557858529 2.645990996825276 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87221.95238863592 2.6713590013969224 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87366.24164248169 2.495335997082293 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87183.96607524085 2.6664280012482777 milliseconds
result linalg.norm(desc1 - desc2)): 87441.26642263135 2.5408009969396517 milliseconds
```

Comment: In OpenCV, you should get the same result with `cv::norm(desc1, desc2, cv::NORM_L2SQR`. Also, the OP is comparing with Numba when he says LLVM optimized Numpy and is using matrix of size `1x512`, see [his other question](https://answers.opencv.org/question/218313/c-matrix-optimization-which-is-look-slower-than-optimized-python-numpy/). Could be interesting to have the timing with Numba to see how close you can get to C++ performance.

Comment: @Catree Hi
is eigen could be faster than cv matrix operation ?